# cv2.VideoCapture only reads part of an mpg file

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I am using cv2.VideoCapture() to read a video of type .mpg,
the problem is it only reads 6 frames out of a 22 seconds long video.
Anyone know what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Please add a minimal example of the code you are using to read the video, otherwise we likely won't be able to find the problem!

Comment: My code so far is just     cap = cv2.VideoCapture(name_file) and     print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
because VideoCapture doesn't work right

Comment: Does this help print(int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)))?

Comment: I asked this over a year ago so I'm not sure in what context I even did, but thank you for the reply anyway :)